# Getting the name of a solution from external source

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, solution

Is it possible to get the Visual Studio solution name from a program like notepad (outside of Visual Studio)?

I'm developing an app that reads solution and project files for various pieces of information.  Projects are not an issue at all.  I can grab a solution file, determine all the projects and get all the information I want on the projects.  My issue is with the SOLUTION name.  I can see clearly in VS where the solution name can be an independant name that has nothing to do with any project.  But when I open a solution file (*.sln) to find that "name" it's nowhere to be found.

I have read that is could be in the *.suo file but that file is encrypted/compressed or something.

Is it possible to get that actual solution "name" without involving VS?  If needed I can use an API with code obviously.  ;)  - Thanks!

Comment: it wont be in the suo. looks like it simply is the filename... eg YourProject.sln

Comment: @wal is that documented somewhere?  I just tested that and it definitely does work though.

Comment: not sure but you change the filename and the sln name changes

Comment: added as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it simply is the filename... eg YourProject.sln.

I observe when changing the filename the solution name changes in VS after restarting